List of Caret Notation ASCII Control Codes (i.e. ^[[101;6u)
How do I find the caret notation control code for a specific key combination? Is there a list or a table? I am looking for Ctrl + Shift + C, Ctrl + Shift + X, and Ctrl + Shift + V.
Ctrl + Shift + E is ^[[101;6u and Ctrl + Shift + A is '^[[97;6u.
I have tried cat. It does not display the full character code for all key combinations.

SO is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool. We don't accept Can I get a list questions or questions that ask us to find off-site resources. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting. (Did you try this?  https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)

The question does not make much sense IMO. While there is a common convention that, for instance, pressing Control together with the "c" key, generates ASCII code 03 (which is commonly notated as ETX (=end of text)), If you combine it with other modifiers (Shift/Alt/...), it is up to the operating system how it is interpreted. Quite often, Control-Shift-c is taken the same as Control-c. Other combinations don't even produce ASCII characters. For instance, I get a ç when I press Alt-c, and  ∞ when I press Alt together with a comma.

Think I found it.
Here is a list of ASCII binary codes for printable characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters
The second number in the first column is the one I am looking for:
Table of values
The second number for E would be 101, therefore the control code is ^[[101;6u. For C, it is ^[[99;6u, because that second number is 99. A is 97, and the alphabet continues from there in corrasponding numerical order.

Nevermind. These codes are not working for me.

These are ANSI escape codes, specifically ones starting with the control sequence introducer (CSI) ESC [. (^[ is another way to represent Esc itself as a control character.)
Most keys generate the character printed on them: e is the e key, A is Shift-a, etc. Characters starting with ^ are generated by holding down the Control key: e.g., ^e is Control-e, ^A is Control-Shift-a, etc. Other keys don't generate a single character, but rather terminal-specific settings: the Escape key itself generates ^[ (same as Control-[), while the ← key might generate ^[[D.
Most shells map Control-v to a command that will insert the next keypress literally; for instance, on my terminal I saw what the ← key generates by typing Control-v ←.
In general, though, if you want to produce a given sequence, it's better to use the tput command than trying to hard-code a terminal-specific sequence.
